# How to select the distance between two starwheeels holding a bottle?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

If you have some experience in th field of packing and filling can you tell me which two areas should i choose to support the bottle with two starwheels ?

I think the red area should be supported as it has a straight line and the upper area 
But I'm afraid if i didn't support the bottom area the bottle would flip because the movement of the conveyor?

[image]
[image]

Comment: What red area? A diagram would help...

Comment: I added a pic can you check it ?

Comment: Can you put the bottle model into your cad program? That should help designing the thing.